# Drop a Datajoint schema in Matlab? List schemas on the database server?

Tags: datajoint

Looking for how to remove an entire Datajoint schema from the SQL database server using the Matlab 3.4 implementation of datajoint (the equivalent of schema.drop(True) in Python)

as well as how to list all schemas that exist on the server (dj.list_schemas() in Python).

There is a [documentation page](https://docs.datajoint.org/matlab/v3.4/definition/14-Drop.html) for dropping a table and its dependent, but not an entire schema.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB doesn't yet have a full implementation for listing schemas, but there is a workaround through the a connection query:

```
connection = dj.conn;
connection.query('SHOW DATABASES')
```

You can then drop any of the items listed:
`dropQuick(schema)`